# Recursive CTE not getting desired result. How to assign anchor only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

The application is for an employee id get all managers

```
declare @emp table (id  int primary key, mgr int);  
insert into @emp values 
       (1, null)
     , (2, 1)
     , (3, 2)
     , (4, null)
     , (5, 4);
select * from @emp;

; with cte as 
( select e.id, e.mgr, cnt = 1 
  from @emp e  
  union all 
  select e.id, e.mgr, cnt + 1
  from @emp e 
  join cte 
    on cte.mgr = e.id 
) 

 select id, mgr, cnt  
 from cte 
 where id = 3;
```

The above only returns the single row for id = 3. I get that is expected but not what I desire. I want to start (anchor) at 3 and get the manager chain.

If I hard code the anchor I get the desired result.
See below:

```
; with cte as 
( select e.id, e.mgr, cnt = 1 
  from @emp e 
  where e.id = 3 
  union all 
  select e.id, e.mgr, cnt + 1
  from @emp e 
  join cte 
    on cte.mgr = e.id 
) 

 select id, mgr, cnt  
 from cte;
```

My question is how to assign the anchor (top part) only in a `where` on the cte?
If not in the `where` is there another way to assign the anchor only (not hard coding in the cte)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the starting position in your cte:

```
declare @emp table (id  int primary key, mgr int);  
insert into @emp values 
       (1, null)
     , (2, 1)
     , (3, 2)
     , (4, null)
     , (5, 4);

; with cte as 
( select e.id ori, e.id, e.mgr, cnt = 1 
  from @emp e  
  union all 
  select cte.ori,  e.id, e.mgr, cnt + 1
  from @emp e 
  join cte 
    on cte.mgr = e.id 
) 

 select ori, id, mgr, cnt  
 from cte 
 where cte.ori = 3;
```

Result:

```
+-----+----+------+-----+
| ori | id | mgr  | cnt |
+-----+----+------+-----+
|   3 |  3 | 2    |   1 |
|   3 |  2 | 1    |   2 |
|   3 |  1 | NULL |   3 |
+-----+----+------+-----+
```

Comment: That works.  I cannot accept yet.  I thought I tried your answer but must have had something wrong.

Comment: @Paparazzi With larger tables this will get very slow. It is calling the recursive part for each and any level over and over... You might add `where not exists(SELECT 1 FROM @emp AS x WHERE e.id=x.mgr)` to start from leaf nodes only... But the best is - if you know this in advance - to sepcify the most narrow anchor. A recursive CTE is a hidden RBAR...

Comment: HoneyBadger, you should reduce the anchor to the most narrow set (see comment above or read my answer). This is working, but the price is very high...

Comment: @Shnugo, I totally agree, I think your answer (and comments) cover that pretty thoroughly. It's up to OP to decide whether the price is too high.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Sure, no problem with this... But anyway: Adding a filter for the leaf-nodes to the anchor would at least avoid overlapping chanins in the result which will bloat this solution even more - without changing the result...

Comment: Got what I asked for, thanks.  My organization is not AT&T.   I also want to report for the whole organization (no where) - the ori to sort on is critical for that query.

Answer (score 2):

I made just one change and removed (seemingly) unnecessary column:

```
declare @emp table (id  int primary key, mgr int);  
insert into @emp values 
       (1, null)
     , (2, 1)
     , (3, 2)
     , (4, null)
     , (5, 4);
select * from @emp;

; with cte as 
( select e.id, e.mgr
  from @emp e  
  union all 
  select cte.id, e.mgr
  from @emp e 
  join cte 
    on cte.mgr = e.id 
) 

 select id, mgr
 from cte 
 where id = 3;
```

Result is:

```
id | mgr
3  | 2
3  | 1
3  | NULL
```

Comment: So, what would be desired output? `3 | 2, 1` ?

Comment: Yes walk the management chain.  Accepted answer shows desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You must decide whether to

- start with a root node (add `WHERE mgr IS NULL` or an explicit id to your anchor) and move down the chain, or to
- start with any child node (add `where not exists(SELECT 1 FROM @emp AS x WHERE e.id=x.mgr)` to the anchor) and move up or to
- start with an explicit child (add `where e.id=3` to the anchor) and move up.

The **general advise** is: Start with the **narrowest anchor-set** possible!

The first query you state in your question (as well as other answers here) will do a **huge overdose** creating **each an any chain** starting from everywhere with **overlapping results**.

As the **recursive CTE is a hidden RBAR** the engine has no chance to predict its result and will create the full load - just to throw most of this away.

If this is a `1:n` relation (always 1 mgr on-top) moving upwards will be much faster. Starting from a given child node You have exactly one step per level - that's it.

Applying the filter in a `WHERE` **after** the recursice CTE was worked out, means to create any possible chain just to throw most of them away...

Your second approach is the best I can think of actually.

So the question is: Why do you want to apply this filter at the end?

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes, sure, but the price is **very high**. If your list is small - no problem, but the approach is - to be honest - the worst you could take...

Comment: @Paparazzi i See that you've accepted this answer already. This is your choice of course. But you should at least add the condition to your anchor to start with leaf-nodes only... (see the comment below HoneyBadger's answer). The answer - as is - is extremely redundant...

Comment: @Paparazzi Do you have a reason, why you want to apply the filter at the end?

Comment: I understand the price high.   Another query is  select ori, id, mgr, cnt  from cte  order by ori, cnt.

Comment: @Paparazzi I've updated my answer, you might read it for some details. If your list is small - go ahead. If you have larger sets you should rethink this...

Comment: I heard you the first time.

Comment: @Paparazzi Did not want to annoy you... Just got the feeling, that hearing and understanding is not always the same... Happy Coding!